# Python transfer code with json

Tags: python, json, eval

Is it possible to use json to execute code? For example can I pass a code object into it or something along those lines? 
I guess my question is how does python evaluate json objects, and can this be used to run code? 
I want to make sure passing information with json is safe from remote execution.

Comment: Not really, but it entirely depends on the situation and your use.  Google JSON security or JSON Injection Attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a Unicode string that contains JSON text; it is always safe <sup>(as far as any C code that accepts user input can be)</sup> to pass it to `json.loads()`.

Where you pass the results of `json.loads()` is up to you: if you want to interpret the received data as code; you can do it.